# why is jenkins removing empty directories from downloaded git repo?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, laravel-5

I'm using Jenkins to deploy a Laravel application to Elastic Beanstalk AWS service.

Its working fine but for some reason the zip file that is being created by Jenkins doesn't contains directories which has only .gitignore file inside. Example:

```
/bootstrap
    app.php
    /cache
        .gitignore
/storage
    /app
        .gitignore
    /framework
        .gitignore
    /logs
        .gitignore
```

None of these directories with .gitignore are present in zip file generated by Jenkins and this is causing errors in AWS.

Maybe should I set some configuration on git clone command in Jenkins?

Comment: Are you sure that it's git issue ?? or zip issue ?? Can you check your workspace and see if the empty directories are present or not ?? if it is present then it will be a zip issue :)

Comment: partially solved by creating dummy files on .gitignore folders =(

Comment: created an issue in github about this: https://github.com/ingenieux/awseb-deployment-plugin/issues/83